# Show that the given subspace $V_0$ is dense in $V$.

Tags: normed-spaces

The conditions are given as the following.

Let $V$ be a normed space and $V_0$ be a subspace. If there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that
$$\inf_{u\in V_0}\|u-v\|\leq c\|v\|,~\forall v\in V.$$

Need to show that the subspace $V_0$ is dense in $V$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a $v\in V$ and $\delta>0$, so we wish to find some $w\in V_{0}$ such that $w\in B_{\delta}(v)$. Choose an $\epsilon_{0}>0$ small enough such that $\epsilon_{0}<\delta$ and  $c+\epsilon_{0}<1$, then choose a $v_{1}\in V_{0}$ such that $\|v_{1}-v\|\leq(c+\epsilon_{0})\|v\|$, and choose a $v_{2}\in V_{0}$ such that $\|v_{2}-(-(v_{1}-v))\|\leq(c+\epsilon_{0})\|-(v_{1}-v)\|=(c+\epsilon_{0})\|v_{1}-v\|$, so $\|v_{2}+v_{1}-v\|\leq(c+\epsilon_{0})^{2}\|v\|$. Choose $v_{3}\in V_{0}$ such that $\|v_{3}-(-(v_{2}+v_{1}-v))\|\leq(c+\epsilon_{0})\|-(v_{2}+v_{1}-v)\|=(c+\epsilon_{0})\|v_{2}+v_{1}-v\|$, so $\|v_{3}+v_{2}+v_{1}-v\|\leq(c+\epsilon_{0})^{3}\|v\|$.

Repeat this way we get $w\in V_{0}$ such that $\|w-v\|\leq(c+\epsilon_{0})^{N}\|v\|$, where $(c+\epsilon_{0})^{N}\|v\|<\epsilon_{0}$, so $w\in B_{\delta}(v)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really bad at constructing problem such like this.